# Why Message content clipped in mails

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I'm using magento 2.0.7 with custom theme and I get the following issue in all mails.But it is properly working in luma theme.

[image]

Comment: If you  got your answer, please mark as valid answer, so others also can use same idea if having same concern. I checked your profile, you asked many questions and got answer as well but you not marked as valid answer. It's an request to mark valid answer which you feel that suites to your requirement or to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow any one of logic

**Logic 1).**

```
@import 'source/_theme.less';
```

remove or comment out `@import _theme.less` line from `email related less` file

because we are working for our theme and adding **pseudo elements/class** that giving error. after remove this line you will get mail without clip text.

OR

**Logic 2).**

In  `_theme.less` don't add any **pseudo elements/class** so when less/css compile happen for `email.css`. you will get proper css, so you will get mail without clip text.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this issue and it was driving me crazy but I finally figured out what was causing it. I sent an email to an `@mailinator.com` email address and changed the view mode to 'Show Original' so I could see all the data being passed.

It turns out, all the css from `_theme.less` was being compiled into `email.css`. If you're like me and put your entire website's styling into `_theme.less` then your emails contain all that styling as well.

By overriding `app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/web/css/email.less` and removing the `_theme.less @import` I was able to get the file size back down and see emails without clipping!